# How to download files from FTP Server

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm trying to download a file (all kinds of files, exe dll txt etc.). And when I try to run it an error comes up on:

```
using (FileStream ws = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create))
```

This is the error message:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions  
\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.1.41\deploy'(which is my destination, where I want 
to save it) is denied.
```

Here is my code

```
void download(string url, string destination)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
        request.UseBinary = true;

        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream rs = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (FileStream ws = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int bytesRead = rs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        ws.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = rs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are we supposed to do about it? Your application has no write-access to the path you specified. Make sure it does. It's your system.

Comment: You have provided almost no information. You ask: "Here is a very general error message. I have done nothing to resolve the problem. I have not researched the error message. I give you no other relevant information. Please solve my problem."

Comment: What are we supposed to do

Answer (score 2):

The error is explicit and clear: your don't have write permissions on `C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.1.41\deploy`

Your program needs this permission to write the file a the specified location.

Comment: Yeah, I figured too. But I tried to go to the file, and click "properties" to change the permission. So i unmarked the "Read Only", but then after I click "OK", the mark is on read only again :(

Comment: Check the permissions of the parent directory, try to create a file manually inside it.

Comment: I changed the permission for the folder "Riot Games" and it will auto. change all the permission for the folders under it. But it doesn't seem to be working. And im sorry :( i don't get what you mean by create a file manually inside it. What I'm trying to do here just download a dll file from my FTP sever :(

Comment: I meant try to crate a file at that location, manually, as your program would do. Check that it is not readonly.

Comment: @user3696888 if you "figured this" already, why are you asking and not telling us this? You provided almost no information.

Answer (score 0):

When he says create a file manually, right-click inside the folder->New->Text file, or whatever you wish to create, just to check if you can. If not, try checking permissions for the parent directory.